# Can i use Autoscaling Application Block to scale Azure VM role instances?

Tags: azure, wasabi

Can i use the Autoscaling Application Block for balancing/scaling the Azure VM role instances?
If this is possible, do i need to include Autoscaling Application Block in the service model definition which is for the virtual machine role? 
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you should be able to target VM roles as Wasabi goes through the standard [Windows Azure Management API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/ee460799.aspx). See the [Design of Wasabi](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh680880%28v=pandp.50%29) section for more info.

Answer (score 2):

WASABi uses standard Diagnostics and Management API which are fully supported by the VM Role.  However, if you're not able to get WASABi to work with your VM Role, you can try [AzureWatch](http://www.paraleap.com), a third-party SaaS monitoring & auto-scaling service

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, I'll try to make wasabi working with vm role. If not, i'll try the AzureWatch.

Answer (score 1):

No WASABI is not supported for VM Role. It is primarily designed and tested with Web/Worker Roles only. The fact is that if you understood WASABI and plan to use WASABI in VM Role, you might be better of using Web/Worker role instead of using VM Role.

Visit link below for more info:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/agile/archive/2011/08/23/autoscaling-windows-azure-applications.aspx